# Custom firmware for Asus WL-520g

Tags: router, firmware

What custom firmware works with Asus WL-520g? (Note this is not 520gU, 520gC, etc.)

I failed to flash it with **Tomato** (Tomato_1_28_ND.zip) - the admin UI does not accept the file, and when trying to tftp the file as [adviced for 520gU](http://file:///C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/Temporary%20Directory%201%20for%20Tomato_1_28_ND.zip/readme.htm#asus520gu) all I get is this:

```
Transfering file tomato-ND.trx to server in octet mode...
Error occurred during the file transfer (Error code = 0):
Error in SendPacket() call.
```

I just saved the router form rather unsuccessful flash to **DD-WRT** (after few hours the router fell into coma), and I'd like to keep it as a backup should the new one die or whatever. (Unfortunately the stock firmware does not support WOL.)

Comment: The Micro version of DD-WRT is alleged to work OK? http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Asus

Comment: I've tested both of them, but there seem to be a problem of CPU load locking at 100%. After a while of playing with web-UI the router ceases to respond.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenWRT](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=8802) can be stripped down to run.  You will have minimal memory and space.  You may be able to add network disk storage.

Comment: Thanks BillThor, but that'd require to learn how to build/compile this stuff, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Jaroslav Unfortunately it would.  The documentation indicates your router has extremely limited resources.